# How can I lifecycle managed object in a Dagger graph

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger

I can't see any support for life-cycle management in Dagger. Only DI, and nothing for @PostConstruct or @PreDestroy.

I'd like Dagger to start/stop object is the graph in the same manner Spring does. How can I do this?

Comment: What is the problem you need to solve?

Comment: I have clarified, how it makes more sense.

Comment: I was looking for this as well. I think this is out-of-scope, dagger only does DI. In my small application's Main class I just created a `shutDown` method which would do the `@PreDestroy`.

Comment: @MirkoFriedenhagen how do you call `shutDown`, manually or do you use Dagger to automatically call it for you?

Comment: @AlexCollins it sounds like you've found a [solution](http://www.alexecollins.com/content/dagger-di-spring-refuges-10-tips/) can you explained further?

Comment: I just did it manually in a finally, nowadays I mostly do tooling/build-engineering and unless forced do DI completely manually, see http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/10/di-containers-are-code-polluters.html as well ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The life-cylce of objects in the graph is the same as the life-cycle of the graph itself. As soon as the graph gets garbage collected, so will all objects within the graph.

I accomplish this by creating sub-graphs in Dagger. The sub-graph will contain all objects (singletons within that graph) that require a shorter life-cycle. Application-wide objects go in the main graph which the sub-graph is dependent on.

PS. I am not familiar with Spring so I can't explain how this relates to Spring.

Answer (score 0):

Opened https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/455 to find out if this is planned or will never be implemented.  @Alex-Collins solution (workaround?) is [via a LifeCycleManager](https://github.com/alexec/openbookmaker/blob/14af37a9e9a89094fcefd92a2f43393894835f2c/src/main/java/com/alexecollins/openbookmaker/LifeCycleManager.java) and [explicit register() in the Dagger Module Provides](https://github.com/alexec/openbookmaker/blob/14af37a9e9a89094fcefd92a2f43393894835f2c/src/main/java/com/alexecollins/openbookmaker/sports/OpenbookmakerModule.java).